# Inequalities involving Maclaurin Series of $1-e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, power-series

Suppose you are given with the first three terms of the Maclaurin Series expansion of the function $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$

Then show, with reasoning, that

$f(x)>x-x^2/2$  for $0<x<2$.

Now, I began by deriving the expansion and it was like this

$f(x)=1+x/1-x^2/2+...$.

But I don't understand the logic behind the inequality, could anyone please explain why the above inequality holds.

Comment: The expansion for $e^{-x}$ starts with 1, so f(x) must start with an x term.

Comment: I think that if one considers the fact that the series is decreasing, for x values between 0 and 2. But this argument does not seen convincing.

Comment: How about looking at the derivative of $1-e^{-x}-(x-\frac{x^2}{2})$?

Comment: Yeah, I know that method, where you could check whether the function is decreasing or not and then with appropriate values of x establish the inequality. But the problem is that the question states that one must use the Maclaurin series expansion.

Comment: True. Do you know the remainder form of such a series (which comes from the Intermediate Value Theorem)?

Comment: No. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: This says that there is a c in (0, x) such that $f(x) = f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(c)$ so you have an estimate of the error term beyond $x^2$.